# Crashes showing up in Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

We've been seeing a lot of crashes on Android showing up in our Google Play Console, but we've been unable to replicate them. It appears to be only a few devices, but no specific OS versions, or manufacturer types, some devices are registering 15-20 crashes in a single day, which leads us to believe that it's not an actual app crash, but something (probably an extension) triggering a crash report, that doesn't impact the actual running of the game. Has anyone else experienced this? Here's what our report says.

```
    Yesterday, 8:18 PM on app version 2001012
Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2qltetmo), 4096MB RAM, Android 7.0
Report 1

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3324)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1727)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6642)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1468)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3319)
```

Comment: Here is quite an old quote, worthy of repeat "`Your classpath is broken (which is a _very_ common problem in the Java world).`" The **reasons** for it grow, as Android grows more complex. `DEX` loading methodologies being one. Is recovery possible ?, sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Android is open source, so it's good to go and look at the source code.
A [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=android+ActivityThread.java) for "android ActivityThread.java" quickly [finds the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java) (for at least one version of the OS).

Ignoring the line numbers, we know the exception happens in the `handleReceiver()` method where it does a `loadClass()`. A *find* in the browser finds [line 3181 (right now)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#3181).

This appears to be loading the component from the classname found in the intent:

```
String component = data.intent.getComponent().getClassName();
...
receiver = (BroadcastReceiver)cl.loadClass(component).newInstance();
```

So if it was me, I would double check your [BroadcastReceivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) in your manifest to make sure they are all configured correctly.